# Route with directive as template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

How to pass a fields variable to directive in ng route configuration, Or in another phase?

```
.when('/test',{template:"<my-directive fields=field></my-directive>"})
```

How to assign param to directive in routing phase?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Like which attributes you want to set? Could you show us your controller if any?

Comment: i need to assign fields to directive as i explain above, my question is : from where i will bring fields parameters ? am i should use resolve to return fields or from directive controller i should get fields ?

Comment: Normally, you would prepare the data (e.g. the `$scope`) inside the controller and that data is then accessible from the template.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting, but i need same controller to use with multiple data, so that i don't want to use $scope in controller, i need to use same controller with multiple params?

Comment: I'll need more details to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include your directive when defining the module dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myDirective' // here, you need to include your directive module
]);
```

Then, define your routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { template: "This is the default Route" })
        .when('/test', {
            template: '<my-directive fields="field"></my-directive>',
            controller: 'testController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

And a controller:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.field = { your: "data here" };

}]);
```